# Setting MaskedEditValidator MaxValue From Code Behind Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to set MaxValue of MaskedEditValidator which is of date type but it is not Validating on the MaxValue after click on Submit Button. Below Is my HTML Code for Masked Edit Validator

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLectureDate" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Select End Date" TabIndex="3" OnTextChanged="txtEndDate_TextChanged" ValidationGroup="Submit" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:TextBox>
<ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender ID="cldrexEndDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtLectureDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="imgECal"
CssClass=" cal_Theme1">
</ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender>

<ajaxtoolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="meeEndDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtLectureDate" Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" AcceptNegative="Left" MessageValidatorTip="false" InputDirection="LeftToRight">
</ajaxtoolkit:MaskedEditExtender>

<ajaxtoolkit:MaskedEditValidator ID="mevEndDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLectureDate" ControlExtender="meeEndDate" IsValidEmpty="false" EmptyValueMessage="Please Enter End Date" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Valid Date in [dd/MM/yyyy]" InvalidValueMessage="Please Enter Valid Date" MaximumValueMessage ="Attendance Date Should Not Be Greater Than Current Date" ValidationGroup="Submit" Display="None">
</ajaxtoolkit:MaskedEditValidator>
```

And below is my Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        mevEndDate.MaximumValue = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(5.5).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
}
```

Please Help Me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that MaskedEdit.UserDateFormat="DayMonthYear". Also I noticed, that validation occurs only on textbox blur.